# C++: overloading method with parameters of multiple subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, subclass

I am making chess, it's a great way to practice basic OOP. There's an abstract base class `Piece` with subclasses like `King`, `Rook`, `Pawn`, etc. as well as a `Board` class.

Is there a way to create multiple overloaded functions in the board class, which perform different operations depending on the parameter's subclass? Here's what I mean, in very barebones class structure:

```
class Piece {};

class King : public Piece {};

class Rook: public Piece {};

class Pawn: public Piece {};

class Board {
public:
  void move_piece(King piece) {
    ;
  }

  void move_piece(Rook piece) {
    ;
  }

  void move_piece(Pawn piece) {
    ;
  }
};

int main() {
  Board game;
  Pawn pawn;
  Piece p = pawn;
  game.move_piece(p);
}
```

I've tried implementing this, however when I pass a piece to this overloaded function, it's declared as a `Piece`, not a `Rook` or `Pawn`. This leads to the following error:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "Piece" to "Pawn" exists
```

Fair enough. But is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: please post a [mcve] of your code

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do. Do you want to impl a function that accepts a base class ptr and invokes one of it's virtual methods? Then `move_piece(Piece* p) { p->move(); }` Do you want to have function that behaves differently depending on the concrete type of the argument? Then `do_sth(const King& k) { k.something(); }`.

Comment: Also, are you sure you actually need the inheritance here? In chess the only difference between figures is the set of available moves, that can be easily modelled by composition of properties.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing, you need to use references otherwise `p` isn't a ` Pawn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some mock implementations and see where this gets us:

```
void move_piece(Pawn piece) {
  //get user to move the piece
  Move mv = GetUserToChoose(possiblePawnMoves(piece));
  if(mv.isNull()) { //if user decided he doesn't want to move this piece
    //??? How do we signal he should choose another?
    return;
  }
  piece.move(mv);
}
```

Oops. `piece` within this function would be a copy of `pawn` outside so any changes to its own state will be discarded when you exit `move_piece()`. *Do you want* to change some internal `pawn` state? For example, consider whether the pawn is legible for [en passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant): who, exactly, has to memorize that? If it's the `pawn` then

```
Piece p = pawn;
```

is a terrible idea. Well, it's a terrible idea in general: when you assign an object of derived type to the object of its base type, *the parts unique to the derived object don't get copied!* It's called [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) and is almost never what you wanted to do. (In addition, you're making another copy: any changes of `p` won't affect `pawn`, even within their common state.) If your different objects have their own states, not saved in a general `Piece`, then you should keep them in variables of their proper types.

So you could do something like:

```
void move_piece(Pawn& piece){ //we potentially change pawn state
  Move mv = GetUserToChoose(possiblePawnMoves(piece));
  if(mv.isNull()) { //if user decided he doesn't want to move this piece
    //??? How do we signal he should choose another?
    return;
  }
  piece.move(mv);
}
//...
  Board game;
  Pawn pawn;
  game.move_piece(p); //compiler chooses overload Board::move_piece(Pawn&)
```

All is good? Eh... *why* did you try to pass a `Piece` object in the first place? Probably because you want to have a set of `Piece`s and move them in a uniform fashion, something like

```
std::vector<Piece> pieces;
//...
board.move_piece(pieces[i]); // want to call Board::move_piece(Rook&)
++i;
board.move_piece(pieces[i]); // want to call Board::move_piece(Knight&)
```

As written, it can't be done. Sorry. The compiler has to decide what function address to put in place of the call, but `Board::move_piece(Rook&)` and `Board::move_piece(Knight&)` are different functions with different addresses. In other words, you need to make the call address dependent on *runtime* data somehow. One option (described in **Jan Schultke** answer) would be to invert the choice logic and use virtual functions:

```
class Pawn : public Piece {
  //...
  virtual void move_on(Board& board){ 
    board.move_piece(*this); //overload resolution chooses Board::move_piece(Pawn&)
  }
  //...
};
//...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece>> pieces; //save POINTERS, no slicing
//...
pieces[i]->move_on(board); // invokes Board::move_piece(Rook&);
++i;
pieces[i]->move_on(board); // invokes Board::move_piece(Knight&);
```

(technically this is achieved via `(pieces[i]->pVTable)[MOVE_FUNC](board)` where `pVTable` is a "hidden" member of `Piece` filled with different addresses in constructors of different classes). Alternatively you may use a simpler approach and dispatch the call yourself:

```
enum class PieceType {
  Pawn,
  Rook, 
  //...
};
class Piece {
  public: PieceType type;
  Piece(PieceType t) : type(t) {}
  //...
};
class Pawn : public Piece {
  //...
  Pawn(void) : Piece(PieceType::Pawn) {}
  //...
};
//...
class Board {
  void move_piece_dispatch(Piece* piece){
    if(piece == nullptr) return MayStartPanickingNow();
    switch(piece->type){
      case PieceType::Pawn: return move_piece(static_cast<Pawn&>(*piece));
      //...
      default: return MayStartPanickingNow();
    }
  }
//...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece>> pieces; 
//...
board->move_piece_dispatch(pieces[i].get()); // invokes Board::move_piece(Rook&);
++i;
board->move_piece_dispatch(pieces[i].get()); // invokes Board::move_piece(Knight&);
```

Alternatively alternatively, if you want to get some interesting practice, you may keep your own table of `Board` functions in `Piece` subtypes:

```
class Piece {
  //...
  std::function<void(Board&)> move;
  //...
};
class Pawn : public Piece {
  Pawn() {
    move = [this](Board& board){return board.move_piece(*this);};
  }
  //...
};
//...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece>> pieces; 
//...
pieces[i]->move(board); // invokes Board::move_piece(Rook&);
++i;
pieces[i]->move(board); // invokes Board::move_piece(Knight&);
```

The function overload is chosen based on object type in its constructor and saved in the `std::function` object for future use.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you've written would work if you knew the exact type of a `Piece`. In that case, *static polymorphism* through functions is good enough.

The issue is that `Piece` is polymorphic (i.e. *dynamic polymorphism*), and the compiler can't automatically know whether to call the function that takes `Rook`, `Pawn` etc.
A poor-man's solution would be to attempt downcasting to the each possible type of `Piece` with `dynamic_cast`, but that defeats the purpose of polymorphism.

Instead, consider what is different between the `Piece`s in the context of moving them:

- a piece has different squares it can move to (e.g. a `Pawn` can move forward)
- moving to a square has different outcomes, e.g. simply moving, taking the opponent's piece, promotion to a queen, winning the game, etc.

You could implement this as abstract virtual functions like:

```cpp
enum class MoveType { None, Move, Attack, Promote };

struct MoveResult {
    MoveType type;
    // A move might also take a piece from the opponent.
    // In the case of en passant, this is not the square that is being moved to.
    Piece* taken_piece;
};

class Piece {
    // ...
  public:
    virtual ~Piece() = default; // virtual destructor almost certainly needed

    virtual MoveResult move(Square) = 0;
};

class Pawn : public Piece {
    // ...
  public:
    MoveResult move(Square s) final {
        if (/* can't move to square */) {
            return { MoveType::None, nullptr };
        }
        if (/* can move forward to the square */) {
            if (/* promotion */) {
                return { MoveType::Promote, nullptr };
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

All the piece-specific logic is now contained within each derived class of `Piece`, and the `Board` can implement `move_piece` without knowing anything about these details:

```cpp
// important: pass by reference to avoid object slicing
void Board::move_piece(Piece& piece) {
    Square target = /* ask user for target square */;
    MoveResult result = piece.move(s);

    if (result.type == MoveType::None) {
        // this move is invalid!
        // the user should try entering another move
    }
    if (result.type == MoveType::Promote) {
        // let the user decide what piece to promote to
    }
    if (/* other checks */) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation of `move_piece` is just pseudo-code.
In practice, you'll probably have to list all possible moves at the start of a round, since the game is a tie when no move is possible.